# Google E-Commerce Tracking

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics

I'm trying to submit data to Google E-Commerce Tracking but it doesn't seem to be working and I think it's because i've had to split the code apart...

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXX-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  _gaq.push(['_addTrans',
    '{{$id}}',           // transaction ID - required
    '{{$name}}',  // affiliation or store name
    '{{$amount}}'          // total - required
  ]);

</script>


@foreach ($products as $product)
<script type="text/javascript">
      _gaq.push(['_addItem',
        '{{$id}}',           // transaction ID - required
        '{{$product['edg_code']}}',           // SKU/code - required
        '{{$product['product_name']}}',        // product name
        '{{$product['unit_price']}}',          // unit price - required
        '{{$product['quantity']}}'               // quantity - required
      ]);
      _gaq.push(['_trackTrans']); //submits transaction to the Analytics servers
</script>

@endforeach

<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Am I missing something or is it because i've split the script apart?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how "it doesn't seem to be working"? Are you seeing error messages, do you not see data populating in your reports, etc?

Answer (score 0):

The Google Analytics script should come before the track pageview and add transaction, it would be something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">


(function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();


  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXX-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  _gaq.push(['_addTrans',
    '{{$id}}',           // transaction ID - required
    '{{$name}}',  // affiliation or store name
    '{{$amount}}'          // total - required
  ]);


@foreach ($products as $product)
//the rest....
</script>
```

see if it works.

Comment: Hi, this isn't necessarily true. Check out the Asynchronous Example at https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingEcommerce#Example

Comment: oh, ok then, I didn't notice anything wrong in his code, what do you suggest?